# Finding my Bitcoin

Tags: client

Around 20 years ago I was watching ad and playing online short games and they mining me Bitcoin. Now I have the email address but I couldn't find any email regarding that. In my inbox only shows the email for 2004 to present. Now I want to is there any way to I can find my Bitcoins?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin was released in 2009, so if what you lost is bitcoin then your email database should be sufficient to find it.

Comment: Do you know what should I look in my inbox to get there?